# Inter vlan routing through Layer3 switch vs Router

Tags: routing, vlan, switching

I am trying to understand a network configuration that I have recently inherited. I am trying to diagnose slow network speeds, internet latency, dropped packets... you name it, the network it kind of a mess.

We have several Vlan's, one for voice, one for data, one for wireless and one camera traffic and my manager tells me that we are utilizing our layer3 switch to route between them. My question is this...

Is it best to route between our vlans through the router, or the layer3 switch?

It seems that my manager (not knowing much about vlan configuration) has static routes in the router as well as the switch.... Is this a problem?? Could this be part of my networking issue?

Comment: Most of your questions really depend on your topology. Using L3 switches for routing is not bad per se (it even has advantages), and static routes are not a bad thing either, depending on where you use them. If you want to get a useful answer, you need to post a *lot* more details about your setup.

Comment: I guess my question is more about whether utilizing both is a problem. for instance, we separate camera traffic through vlan (in the switch) but then there is a route from the camera segment to the data segment. Doesn't this defeat the purpose of separating the traffic?

Comment: Utilizing both might have it's advantages as well, again depending on why and how they're used. For a camera VLAN I can imagine that it's a good idea to seperate traffic because camera's might be outside the building and people with malicious intent can get access to the network without needing physical access inside the building.

Comment: Based on the symptoms you describe I think it's best if you first check the CPU (punting) and interrupt levels on both devices. Also check link utilization for every single port and see if there might be a problem there.

Comment: `1.` Don't cast stones. You say the network is a mess yet you're unable to grasp the use of VLAN's and static routing. That tells me that you're not qualified to make a judgment on the state of the network or your predecessor. `2.` There's nothing inherently wrong with routing in the switches. `4.` There's nothing inherently wrong with static routing. `5.` You need to break the network down into its component pieces and troubleshoot it. Start from your workstation and work outward from there. `6.` We're going to need a lot more detail from you about the topology in order to give you an answer.

Comment: I'm not qualified to make judgement on the state of the network? Its easy to spot problems on a network, especially when its not functioning properly. My question is better asked whether allowing vlan traffic to transverse onto the data segment could be reducing throughput. We have around 60 cameras each of which are 5mp each. It generates a lot of traffic. Just trying to make sure there isn't a miss configuration.